# Use of At the double

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I see the phrase "at the double", but it seems not so common. It should be "on the double". Is it right?

> Zaha **at the double** as he and Mateta run riot over Steven Gerrard’s
> Villa

https://t.co/1mNDmRnyZ8

Comment: Both acceptable https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at-on-the-double

Comment: Each is only acceptable in the corresponding country, 'on' is US, 'at' is UK [as a Brit, 'on' sounds totally wrong to me]. Both are military terms for marching quickly [literally, double time]. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31024/origin-of-expression-at-the-double

Answer (score 2):

The idiom I believe you are thinking of - meaning to do something faster - can be either 'on the double' or 'at the double'. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20the%20double%2C%20on%20the%20double&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20double%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20double%3B%2Cc0) shows that both are used in literature, with 'on the double' being used slightly more often.

However, I don't think that is what is meant in your particular example. If it was, it wouldn't make sense.

'The double' has a number of unique uses in the game of football. I think it can mean winning two games in a row, beating the same team at home and away in the same season, winning two different cups, and possibly other uses too. I don't really follow football, but from the opening paragraph of that article it sounds like the player named has had two successful games in a row, and I think that is what is meant.

Comment: That's right, Wilfred Zaha scored twice, a "double".  I think the Sun's subeditor has tried to make a pun - but it's not quite right.